# Jqgrid : Using column freezing along with grouping

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, grouping, freeze

I'm working in a project that use Jqgrid to display some excel-like table. It contains a couple of columns.
Now we managed to group by one column called "Transaction". Below that group header is the left-most column named Customers.

The remaning columns are Items which are sold to those customers.
Now the users want the entire Customers column frozen (along with the transaction group header text). So that when they scroll, the first column always stay in sight.

It's quite difficult because jqgrid doesn't support column freezing with grouped column . I've searched many places but no clues was found.

Please help me achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

The [`setFrozenColumns`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3afrozencolumns) method is available in jqGrid since version 4.3.0. By using that u can achieve this